# PySpark: TypeError: StructType can not accept object in type <type 'unicode'> or <type 'str'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading data from a CSV file and then creating a DataFrame. But when I try to access the data in the DataFrame I get TypeError.

```
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schema.split(',')]
schema = StructType(fields)

input_dataframe = sql_context.createDataFrame(input_data_1, schema)

print input_dataframe.filter(input_dataframe.diagnosis_code == '11').count()
```

Both 'unicode' and 'str' are not working with Spark DataFrame. I get the below TypeError:

TypeError: StructType can not accept object in type 
TypeError: StructType can not accept object in type

I tried encoding in 'utf-8' as below but still get the error but now complaining about TypeError with 'str':

```
input_data_2 = input_data_1.map(lambda x: x.encode("utf-8"))
input_dataframe = sql_context.createDataFrame(input_data_2, schema)

print input_dataframe.filter(input_dataframe.diagnosis_code == '410.11').count()
```

I also tried parsing the CSV directly as utf-8 or unicode using the param use_unicode=True/False

Answer (score 3):

Reading between the lines. You are

> reading data from a CSV file

and get

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object in type <type 'unicode'>
```

This happens because you pass a string not an object compatible with struct. Probably you pass data like:

```
input_data_1 = sc.parallelize(["1,foo,2", "2,bar,3"])
```

and schema

```
schema = "x,y,z"

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schema.split(',')]
schema = StructType(fields)
```

and you expect Spark to figure things out. But it doesn't work that way. You could

```
input_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input_data_1.map(lambda s: s.split(",")), schema)
```

but honestly just use Spark csv reader:

```
spark.read.schema(schema).csv("/path/to/file")
```

Comment: I get `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'` when I try `spark.read.schema`. I am reading from a directory inside which I have partitioned data with multiple gzipped .csv files